# Question on the Arrays.sort with lambda function's parameter type omitting

Tags: java

I was trying to understand the code that other user submitted as an answer to the leetcode binary search question called "kWeakestRows".

Suppose I have a 2D integer array called "a".

[[1,0],[3,1],[0,2],[1,3],[4,4]]

And if I want to sort the array "a" by the first value of each rows.

So, sort by a[0][0], a[1][0], a[2][0], a[3][0], a[4][0].

```
Arrays.sort(a, (b, c) -> b[0] - c[0]);
```

After calling the sort method, I will have an array that looks like this

[[0,2],[1,0],[1,3],[3,1],[4,4]]

Then I was not sure how the lambda parameter types (b,c) could be omitted ?
Where does the compiler infer the type from ?

Notice how the parameter type int[] for b and c are omitted.

```
Arrays.sort(a, (int[] b, int[] c) -> b[0] - c[0]);

Arrays.sort(a, (b, c) -> b[0] - c[0]);
```

For reference, here is the code example I was trying to understand.

```
public int[] kWeakestRows(int[][] mat, int k) {
        //2D matrix to hold the number of solders in a row and the index the row is at
        int[][] weakest = new int[mat.length][];
        int i = 0;

        for (int[] row : mat) {
            /*
                search method returns the index of the first civilian, so if there
                are only 2 solders, the first index of a civilian is 2
            */
            int solders = binarySearch(row);    //if there are no civilians, the number of soldiers is the length of the row
            weakest[i] = new int[]{solders, i};
            i++;
        }

        //sort weakest by the first value of soldiers
        Arrays.sort(weakest, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0]);

        //add the first k indexes to the result array
        int[] res = new int[k];
        for (int j = 0; j < k; j++) {
            res[j] = weakest[j][1];
        }

        return res;
    }
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If you want (b,c) to be omitted, then you can use ```Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0])```

Comment: @OleV.V. And you are absolutely correct. ;) Here `sort` is a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) and the type is implicitly known from `a`. You can even "pass" it explicitly: `Arrays.<int[]>sort(weakest, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0]);`, which is redundant.

Comment: @OleV.V. I'd rather find the duplicate to close this one, but I can't find one. This seems like such a basic thing, it must have been asked already ..

Comment: Not what you were asking, but I’d prefer to use the version in @prostýčlověk’s first comment, `Comparator.comparingInt(a -> a[0]) `, both because it’s terse and because it’s safe from int underflow and overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of the method you are calling is the following:

```java
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```

This declares a [generic method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html) that introduces the type parameter `T`. This parameter enables you to use the method with any reference type. It's like using a list of e.g. `String`s: `List<String>`, where `String` is the argument for the type parameter `E` within `List`.

The type of `T` can be infered at compile time ([Type Inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html)) as the type of the elements of the array is known as you call the method. When you call the method like `Arrays.sort(weakest, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0])` and `weakest` is declared as `int[][]`, then it's clear that the type of the elements is `int[]`.

The type is infered implicitly but you can provide it explicitly like `Arrays.<int[]>sort(weakest, (a, b) -> a[0] - b[0])`, which is redundant. The types of the parameters for the lambda expression are also infered implicitly. See [Target Typing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

My understanding is as follows -

Given that the second argument is basically a short-hand implementation of the [comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) (functional-interface) and that the type-parameter for the comparator is expected to be a super-type of the first argument, then the type for the comparator arguments would be inferred from the first argument and given that Integer is a supertype of itself as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java), it would be the case that compiler would not have any issues with it.

The method signature looks something like [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort-T:A-java.util.Comparator-) -

```
public static <T> void sort(T[] a, Comparator<? super T> c)
```